# How to use Javascript to submit the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
<?php echo Form::open(array('method' => 'post', 'id' => 'form_public')); ?>
<?php echo Form::csrf(); ?>
<?php echo Form::hidden('publish_flag', \Model_Item_Review::PUBLISH); ?>
<?php echo Form::submit('submit',  'submit', array('id'='public'))?>
<?php echo Form::close(); ?>
```

Below is the js code, modal popup window is used to alert.

```
<button class="btn btn-flat-danger modal-btn-primary btn-block" data-dismiss="modal" id="do_confirm">yes</button>

$('#public').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#warning_modal').html('are you sure?');
    $('#confirmModal').modal('show');
    $('#do_confirm').click(function(){
        $('#form_public').submit();
    });
});
```

When I click yes It shows such an error:`Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`
Why I can't submit the form?thanks a lot.

Comment: I see no public ID, can you jsfiddle?

Comment: My assumption is the name of your submit button is `submit` which is causing the problem... change `<?php echo Form::submit('submit',  'submit', array('id'='refuse'))?>` to `<?php echo Form::submit('submit1',  'submit2', array('id'='refuse'))?>`

Comment: also change `$('#form_public').submit();` to `$('#form_public')[0].submit();`

Comment: not a PHP guy... but I'm assuming the first to params to the `submit()` call are the `name` and `value`... if you can share the generated html for the submit button it will be easier for us to find out the issue

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
<?php echo Form::submit('submit',  'submit', array('id'='refuse'))?>
```

to this

```
<?php echo Form::submit('submit',  'submit', array('id'='public'))?>
```